# Bootstrap 3 'Fixed Navbar' is expanding only about 55-60% of screen height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, expansion

Using opencart and Bootstrap 3, when I click the menu to expand in 'XS' it only expands to about 55-60% of the screen height. How do I make it expand fully, there are like 2-3 menu items that don't get shown the way it is now.

Thanks a million!

Comment: Ca you post some code or a pen? Hard to troubleshoot with no code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I managed to find it in the end. I just added the min-height to this line.

```
#menu .navbar-collapse{padding:0; min-height: 500px;}
```